# Как изменить sh скрипт?

Tags: bash, .bashrc

Есть такой скрипт `m3u_to_userbouquet+v2.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#Преобразует плейлисты .m3u в enigma2 userbouquet
cd /tmp ; find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.m3u" | sed 's/^..//' > list
[ ! -s list ] && echo "Нет ни одного файла .m3u в папке /tmp" && exit
while [ -s list ] ; do
    m3u=`cat list | head -n1`
    name=`echo "$m3u" | sed 's/.m3u//'`
    echo "userbouquet.$name.tv"
    sed -i "1d" list
    sed -i '/^http\|^#EXTINF\|^rtmp/!d' $m3u
    sed -i '/^#EXTINF/N;/\n#EXTINF/D' $m3u
    sed -i '/^http/N;/\nhttp/D' $m3u
    cat $m3u | awk 'NR%2==0 {print $0; print p} {p=$0}' >> file
    sed -i '/#EXTINF/!s/:/%3a/g; s/[[:space:]]$\||User-Agent=.*//; N;s/\n#EXTINF.*,/:/; s/ \+/ /g; s/^http\|^rtmp/#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:&/' file
    sed -f /usr/script/reference -i file
    echo "Референсы добавлены на каналы в \"userbouquet.$name.tv\""
    sed -i "/iptv[12]*.evpanet\|udp\|mpegts/s/SERVICE 4097/SERVICE 1/g; 1s/^/#NAME $name\n/;" file
    mv file /etc/enigma2/userbouquet.$name.tv ; rm $m3u
    if grep -q "userbouquet.$name.tv" /etc/enigma2/bouquets.tv ; then
        echo 'Каналы перезаписаны' ; echo ''
    else
        echo 'Запись каналов в букеты' ; echo ''
        echo "#SERVICE 1:7:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:FROM BOUQUET \"userbouquet.$name.tv\" ORDER BY bouquet" >> /etc/enigma2/bouquets.tv
    fi
done
echo 'Перезагрузка usrbouquet' ; echo ''
wget -q -O - http://127.0.0.1/web/servicelistreload?mode=2 > /dev/null
exit 0
```

Нужно убрать из скрипта строки, чтобы это действие не выполнялось.
echo "Референсы добавлены на каналы в `userbouquet.$name.tv`"
Данные для этой замены скрипт получает из файла; reference
Остальное должно сработать без изменений.

Comment: В чем конкретно заключается ваша проблема? А вы пробовали убрать указанные строки, к чему это привело? Не очень понятна суть вашей проблемы. [Обновите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1482656/edit) ваш вопрос, опишите более детально, что вы попробовали сделать и что у вас не получилось сделать.

Answer (score 1):

> Как изменить sh скрипт?

Скрипт это простой текстовый файл. Окткройте его любым текстовым редактором например `nano` и внесите необходимые изменения:

```
nano m3u_to_userbouquet+v2.sh
```

Для сохранения изменений в `nano` используется комбинация клавиш 'ctrl+o', для выхода из `nano` используется комбинация клавиш 'ctrl+x'.
Если вы хотите удалить какую-то часть скрипта но не уверены в правильности своих действий, можно не удалять а "закомментировать" часть кода и она не будет выполнятся. Для этого необходимо в начале строки напечатать символ **#**, вот так:

```
...
    sed -f /usr/script/reference -i file
#    echo "Референсы добавлены на каналы в \"userbouquet.$name.tv\""
#    sed -i "/iptv[12]*.evpanet\|udp\|mpegts/s/SERVICE 4097/SERVICE 1/g; 1s/^/#NAME $name\n/;" file
#    mv file /etc/enigma2/userbouquet.$name.tv ; rm $m3u
    if grep -q "userbouquet.$name.tv" /etc/enigma2/bouquets.tv ; then
...
```

Если изменения не превели к желаемому результату просто "раскомментируйте" строки, удалив символы **#** в начале строки и попробуйте закомментировать что-то еще. Так методом "научного тыка" можно определить кусок кода выполняющий искомую функцию и удалить/изменить его.

Творите, выдумывайте, пробуйте!)

Comment: можно еще добавить как правильно выключить компьютер после редактирования скрипта ))